# Download a file in Safari by JavaScript without using window.open

Tags: javascript, download, safari

Html5 download attribute doesn't work on Safari.

I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29507802/1127787) but doesn't work for me  since `window.open` is patched on my webpage.

What other options do I have if I want to download the file?