# Javascript download file works only on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

I am using this function, to download a text file.
This code works only on chrome browser,
What is eqivelent code in other browser for

- IE
- Firfox
- Safari

Kindly guide me

```
function downloadFileFnc(text, fileName)
{
    var textCode = new Blob([text], { type: "application/text" });
    var dldLnkVar = document.createElement('a');
    dldLnkVar.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textCode);
    dldLnkVar.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    dldLnkVar.click();
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: No error noting.. It just does not work.

Comment: This question may point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802109/download-blobs-locally-using-safari

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see they suggest FileSaver.js, I need to know the logic they have used in that which works for all browser.